# Scala for loop with multiple variables

Tags: java, scala, for-loop

How can I translate this loop (in Java) to Scala?

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; i++, j++) {
  //Other code
}
```

My end goal is to loop through two lists at the same time.
I want to get both elements at the same time at each index in the iteration.

```
for(a <- list1, b <- list2) // doesn't work

for(a <- list1; b <- list2) // Gives me the cross product
```

Comment: You know the j variable is useless right? Since it will always be equal to i

Comment: You're right. I tried to ask a question that did not directly give me the answer to my problem but in the end I worded it in a bad way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `.zip()` to make a list of tuple and iterate over it.

```
val a = Seq(1,2,3)
val b = Seq(4,5,6)
for ((i, j) <- a.zip(b)) {
  println(s"$i $j")
}
// It prints out:
// 1 4
// 2 5
// 3 6
```

Comment: This works for only two variables, it's not extendable to multiple variables as suggested by the title

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple list to iterate over, just use `.zipped` on the tuple of the lists.

```scala
val l1 = List(1, 2, 3)
val l2 = List(4, 5, 6)
val l3 = List("a", "b", "c")

for ((c1, c2, c3) <- (l1, l2, l3).zipped) {
    println(s"$c1, $c2, $c3")
}

//Prints
1, 4, a
2, 5, b
3, 6, c
```